# IOS splitviewcontroller and size classes

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I Have questions on SplitViewController.

Is possibile to make the same behavior on iPhone and iPad?

I need make on portrait master view and after clicked item show details view. In landscape I need master near details.

My issue is master as slide on iPad at portrait mode ...

Comment: I don't really know, but it sounds like you are trying to re-engineer why Apple made a split view controller. I once almost implemented using one, and if I recall, even IF you subclass it (or roll your own), on many iPhones in landscape mode, that kind of layout (master/detail on one screen) isn't very user-friendly. And yes, if (and hopefully when) Apple reintroduces a 4 inch screen, trust me, it doesn't work well.

Comment: I belive, but my client want this usage ...